# How can I change the Spring batch(Job Repository) oracle datasource schema

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I am using the following oracle DB properties:

```
ds.username=ABC
ds.password=*****
ds.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`*`
ds.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@xyz.com:1521:db1
```

But our DBA created the JobRepository tables on different schema name (SQZ2210) and that is why I am getting table or view doesn't exist error. My analysis is Spring batch JobReposity's schema by default is also the provided username (username=ABS). If my understanding is correct, I need to tell Spring batch to use a different schema name. ex. : `select * from SQZ2210.BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolved this issue by adding schema table prefix. "batch.ds.prefix=XYZ.BATCH_". Just ensure to add ".BATCH_" because Spring Batch truncates this default table prefix name "BATCH_" unless you modify the your JobRepository metadata schema.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

With Oracle, the "user" and "schema" is essentially the same thing (see this [Ask Tom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6162110256950)). So you need to use the credentials for SQZ2210 when making your connection.

This might give you some extra complexity if your business tables are under a different user / different datasource; now you have to be concerned with transactional integrity of the step across multiple datasources (which introduces JTA, XA, etc).

Some argue that the Spring Batch tables should be included with your business tables, because the job metadata is so closely related; i.e. the job *itself* is business data, especially when you considered what might be stored in the job parameters and execution contexts.